# I receive null reference error in xamarin Android google map

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, runtime-error, nullreferenceexception

I want to use google map in my xamarin Android app but in runtime I receive null reference error.

I do all the steps exactly like what I see in
(Xamarin Android Tutorial 40 Google Maps in youtube)
and some how like this (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/)

manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App14.App14" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <application android:label="App14">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

main.axml is like below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and main.activity Is like this

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;

namespace App14
{
    [Activity(Label = "App14", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity , IOnMapReadyCallback
    {

        GoogleMap mMap; 
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            SetUpMap();
        }

        void IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            mMap = googleMap;

        }

        private void SetUpMap()
        {

            if (mMap == null)
            {
                FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: i forgot to mention that .I had installed google play to my emulator too.

Comment: @ondrej why do you think it is not correct? I follow the steps of "Xamarin Android Tutorial 40 Google Maps in youtube"

Comment: I wonder if any one can help

Comment: Sry, I didn't notice you are opening map through android xml. I am using xaml and have different code there.

Comment: @Ondrej it is ok. I searched a lot but I can not find solution for null reference error in run time.

Comment: in https://developer.xamarin.com  I see this  "the GoogleMap will not be ready until some indeterminate amount of time has passed. This is because the initialization for the GoogleMap object can take some time to complete as the API communicates with Google Play", While this initialization is happening, the MapFragment.Map property will return null.

Comment: Just guessing, try to remove call to SetUpMap a and just wait for OnMapReady callback being called.